# Why doesn't the curvature of spacetime around Earth cancel the Sun's curvature?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, curvature, solar-system

If the Sun and Earth both act on the same medium, which is spacetime, then why the Earth curvature of spacetime around itself does not isolate it from the Sun's curvature? If it does not, and the Sun attracts Earth and Earth attracts the Sun, which is what actually happen, then this would mean another thing, their spacetime curvature should add together, therefore Earth should not attract us but we all should "go" to the Sun...

Answer (score 6):

We are falling towards the Sun! Alongside Earth, we are orbiting the Sun. Orbiting *is* a way of falling. The difference between falling straight down, as we often experience on Earth, and orbiting is the amount of angular momentum, i.e., the amount of rotation we have around the place we are "falling to". We happen to be rotating very fast around the Sun, but not that much around the Earth.

Notice that the Moon, on the other hand, is rotating quite fast around the Earth as well, and hence it orbits instead of falling straight down. The same applies, for example, for the astronauts at the International Space Station.

Comment: If earth also warp spacetime, why the curvature around does not isolate it from the curvature of the sun?

Comment: @jaghalli why do you think it would isolate? Both effects contribute (they don't exactly add up, it is more complicated, but both are there). Things close to the Earth do fall towards the Earth, but they fall towards the Sun as well. If we were isolated from the Sun's gravity, the Earth would pass by and we'd be left floating amid nothing

Comment: I just want the exact explanation from GR (without using hard math) of this phenomena, because if Earth warps spacetime and Sun warps spacetime (according to GR), why the Earth's curvature does not isolate it from "touching" the Sun's spacetime curvature? what exactly happens in spacetime between Earth and Sun? If both curvatures add together then it won't be gravity here on earth

Comment: @jaghalli It is not really possible to give an exact explanation without math. The exact explanation is to solve the Einstein Field Equations. Intuitivelly, the point is that the curvature near the Earth is "dominated" by the Earth, and hence things fall towards it. However, since the Earth is falling towards the Sun, we fall along towards the Sun as well (which is due to Sun's influence on the curvature)

Answer (score 0):

> their spacetime curvature should add together, therefore Earth should not attract us but we all should "go" to the Sun.

General relativity is non linear, so it is more complicated than just adding together. But in fact there is some effect.

Curvature of spacetime is tidal gravity. The strongest tides are from the moon, but there are small tides from the sun too. The total tides are largest when both the solar and Lunar tides are involved.

Comment: We still are in a room, did you quit?

Answer (score 0):

It is misconception in relativity that every motion is in inertia or constant speed as in orbits. Only motion on spacetime are inertial, as orbits. But when something moves radially, it crosses potential thus on the expense of energy or due to force. This radial movement is acceleration and on earth we called it as acceleration due to gravity. So orbitting is not similar to falling on earth.

So unless either force need to keep in orbit  that is due to curvature of space, not spacetime. Just because there is need of time component not make it spacetime, because curvature of spacetime can't be measured. Now the force that not keep things in orbit is called as death of star. So star keeps it planets away from it unless dying. So if earth is planet, then it is not falling into sun because it is moving with constant speed on expense of sun's energy.

Yes, curvature due to earth and sun sum together at any point. But, earth can't simply move into its own curvature. Reason is simple, a charge can feel force into the field of another charge and that force depends upon its own value of charge, this goes to Newtonian gravity directly. As theory of relativity is complimentory for Newtonian gravity, so it can't differ on fundamental issues. So there is no concept of self-curvature in relativity. Yet some well known authors wrongly put it as, mass curve spacetime and spacetime direct mass, which is not the case.